# Using spring MVC to transform query parameters into path parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As part of SNS optimization we have to change our query parameters to path parameters, so:

/somesite?hl=ja

Has to become:
/somesite/hl/ja

How do we do that without adding a separate path to every single @RequestMapping method?  It doesn't look like I can do it with an Interceptor.  We are using Spring 4

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `filter` instead of `interceptor` to rewrite the request URI.
If you are free to use any third-party library, you can use this http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/.

Or you can write your own impl in filter method.

Follow this question for implementation. [servlet filter to rewrite URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648437/servlet-filter-to-rewrite-url)